# Access 2D arrays through their pointer

Tags: c, arrays, c99

I'm having some problems trying to access a *true* 2D array in my program.
I have a 1D array that emulates a 2D array to hold some level information (tile based game). When I access to some tile I do the common operations to change row/column index to liniar array:

**The map is allocated in heap, and I hold a pointer to this array in the level struct**

```
size = x * y;
level->map = malloc(size * sizeof(struct _mkTile));
[...]
for (size_t i = 0; i < level->y; i++) {
    for (size_t e = 0; e < level->x; e++) {
        level->map[i * level->y + e].pos.x = xpos;
        [...]
```

I do this operations a lot of times in my code, but recently I want to use a *true* 2D array to make the code more readable. I have a lot of code who relies in this 1D array so I want also to mantain this access form to the map.

Reading trought this site I found how to allocate a 2D array:

```
struct _mkTile(*map)[x] = malloc(sizeof(struct _mkTile[x][y]));
```

I keep the pointer in my struct (level->map) the same, because lot of code expect a 1D array, so I do the following cast `level->map = (struct _mkTile *)map;` So far, so good. The old code works without problems.

At this point I can access my tiles through 2D indexing using the `map[i][e]` pointer, but obiously not the `level->map`:

So the question is, how is the proper declaration of a pointer to a 2D array (with unknow size) which allows using the 2D accessors `[][]`? Is possible to cast back the `level->map` pointer to a *true* 2D array?

Comment: "to make the code more redable. " Do you mean more readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can cast the pointer to 1D array and get a pointer to 2D array.  Start with the same type as when you allocated the 2D array:

```
struct _mkTile(*map2d)[x] = level->map; // type mismatch, see compiler error
```

Add a cast:

```
struct _mkTile(*map2d)[x] = (struct _mkTile(*)[x])level->map;
```

Finally, clean it up with a typedef:

```
typedef struct _mkTile row_t[x];
row_t* map2d = (row_t*)level->map;
```

Comment: So, it's not possible to have a pointer holding a _generic_ 2D array to point diferent sizes 2D arrays withou casting right?

Comment: @Bungow: Right.

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop you assign values in the level->map, indexing looks wrong. Try:

```
 level->map[i * level->x + e].pos.x = xpos;
```

It is `i * level->x + e` because each row `i` has level->x data, not level->y.